# How to pass List<T> from from JS to API

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have below model and Controller. I want to know how to pass value for the API from Ajax call.

Model:

```
Public Class Data
{
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Title {get;set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HTTPPOST]
public string UpsertItems(List<Data> Inputs)
{
 try
  {...}
 catch(Exception ex)
  {..}
}
```

From frontend i need to pass below data to API.

I tried passing data like below

```
var datacoll='{{"ID":1,"Title":"a"},{"ID":2,"Title":"b"}}'
```

If I pass variable datacoll as it is I am getting 500 internal error and if I pass JSON.Stringify(datacoll) in controller i am getting null value.

Ajax method:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/Test/UpsertItems',
  method: 'POST',
  dataType: 'text',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: datacoll,
  success: function (data) {..},
   error: function (jqXHR) {..},
  });
```

Please let me know what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data needs to be a list, notice the square brackets.

```
var datacoll='[{"ID":1,"Title":"a"},{"ID":2,"Title":"b"}]'
```